# Getting .NET to handle CSS files

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, iis-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can .NET intercept and change css files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200427/can-net-intercept-and-change-css-files)

I have configured IIS6 to get .NET to handle css files.

I did the following steps

- Launch IIS Manager
- Right-click on Default Web Site
- Click on the Home Directory tab
- Under Application Settings click on Configuration...
- Add a new association for .css and map it to .NET executable:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

How can I check if this is working, i.e. I want to change the default style of a page depending on the url, i.e. if the referer url is http://intranet, it should continue to use the old existing style `style1.css`, if the referer url is http://intranetv2, it should use the new style `style2.css`.

Comment: How does getting .Net to handle CSS files achieve this? What is .Net supposed to do with a CSS file?

Comment: Using HttpModule or HttpHandlers in .NET.

Comment: @Patrick McDonald, thanks, need a few more votes to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that rather than doing this, you create a HTTP handler to serve your CSS file - this means that if you do have any static CSS files, they can continue to be dispatched quickly.

Example here:

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/variables_in_css

---

Final note from the comments below.  In this case, what you could do is create you handler to serve your css file depending on the URL.  In your project, do a 'replace in all files' of "mystylesheet.css" with "mystylesheethandler.ashx" and away you go.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.  I just just setup the IIS6 server, now I want to test if it's working.

Comment: The link you posted shows, how to make css files variable aware, I am trying to dynamically change the whole style sheet based on the referal url.

Comment: I've just remembered I have another question just like this which I forgot about... Can't delete this question now to continue with that question...

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, in this case.  Surely this is then just a matter of adding a stylesheet in the master page, depending on the URL?  What do you need to configure in IIS to do this?  Would note that you could also do this in a handler.

Comment: I can't use master pages because there were no master pages when I made those old pages with .net 1.0.  It's all explained in my old question, so ideally, I need to close this question and continue with my old question for which I have added a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make changes to your web application itself, not IIS or .NET - they are the runtimes. They run your website, they don't modify it in any way. Those stylesheet changes are a core part of your application, you will need to program it yourself, detecting the URL (or having a separate application altogether) and use the appropriate stylesheet.

Furthermore, I'd like to add that .NET does not "handle" a CSS, or any other file other than PEs and DLLs (from which compiled code is executed). CSS is not compiled code - it does not execute any statements on a machine's processor.